# How to refer a named range in an Excel formula

Tags: excel-formula, spreadsheet

I have a named range in one workbook file which points to another named range in another workbook file, say

```
CityList = AnotherFile.xlsx!Cities.
```

The formula

```
=OFFSET(CityList,MATCH(J6,INDEX(CityList,,2),0)-1,0,COUNTIF(INDEX(CityList,,2),J6),1)
```

works well, however, if I want to make *CityList* as a parameter as I will apply the same formula to different named ranges, how can I make this happen? I tried using *INDIRECT("B6")* to replace *CityList* (B6 has the value of "CityList"), but it didn't work.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the quotes. `=INDIRECT(B6)` should work.